# Jenkinsfile Username and Password credentials cannot pass over to Packer

Tags: aws-cli, jenkins-groovy, packer

I had
Jenkins ver 2.401.3
Packer 1.9.4

Below is my Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
  agent any 
  environment {
      AWS_CRED     = credentials('AWS_SECRET')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Packer - Build Ubuntu Image on AWS') {
      steps {
        sh ''' 
        #!/bin/bash
        packer validate ubuntu-aws.json
        packer build -var access_key=$AWS_CRED_USR -var secret_key=$AWS_CRED_PSW ubuntu-aws.json
        '''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I had difficulties to pass over the credentials.
Error: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors

Error show the credentials has not match however I dont think it cause by Jenkins credentials because I could echo both username and password.

```
{ 

  "variables": {
    "aws_access_key": "",
    "aws_secret_key": "",
    "region": "ap-southeast-1",
    "instance_type": "t2.micro"
  },
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
      "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key` }}",
      "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key` }}",
      "region": "{{user `region` }}",
      "source_ami_filter": {
        "filters": {
          "virtualization-type": "hvm",
          "name": "ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*",
          "root-device-type": "ebs"
        },
        "owners": ["099720109477"], 
        "most_recent": true
      },
      "instance_type": "{{user `instance_type`}}",
      "ssh_username": "{{user `ssh_username`}}",
      "ami_name": "packer-base-{{timestamp}}",
      "subnet_id": "subnet-0eb53daf294979531",
      "associate_public_ip_address": true,
      "user_data_file":"./defaults.cfg"
    }
  ],
```

A snipplet of my code for packer.

What is the correct way to get credentials passing over from Jenkinsfile credentials > Packer > verified by AWSCLI